# Json to String doesn't work

Tags: c#, json

I have a Problem with my software. It is displayed as a json Code in the labels, but I use Serialization to convert it to String but its still shows in a Json Format. This Data comes from a Database.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;




namespace MMPI2_Test
 {
   /// <summary>
/// Interaktionslogik für Patient.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class Patient : Window
{
    public Patient()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += MyWindow_Loaded;
    }

    private void btyes_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    public String MyProperty { get; set; }

    public String Property { get; set; }
    private void MyWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //dynamic convert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(MyProperty);

        string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(MyProperty);
        lbuser.Content = json;


        string tan ="";
        MainWindow main = new MainWindow();
        main.alpha = tan;

        string html = string.Empty;
        string url = @"http://aa.workloud.at/?tag=question&token="+Property;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            html = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        //dynamic magic = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(html);
        string json2 = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(html);
        lbquestion.Content = json2;

          }
         }
       }
```

Edit :

```
        <?php

   /**
   PHP API for MMPI2 Soul - lution
   **/

 header("Content-type: application/json");

 require_once("include/functions.php");
 require_once 'include/DB_Functions.php';

 $db = new DB_Functions();

 $tag = getParamValue("tag");
 $token = getParamValue("token");

 $response = array("data" => null, "tag" => $tag, "error" => null);

   if($token != null)
  {
  $checkToken = $db->validateToken($token);

  if($checkToken === true)
    {
    if($tag == "login")
        {
        global $currentTestName, $currentPatientTestId;
        $response["data"]["fname"] = $currentUser["firstname"];
        $response["data"]["lname"] = $currentUser["lastname"];
        $response["data"]["testname"] = $currentTestName;

        if ($db->startTest() !== true)
        {
            //$response["error"] = "Der Test hat schon eine StartTime";
        }

        }
    elseif($tag == "question")
    {
        // Request type is question
        // list questions
        $questions = $db->listQuestion();
        //echo var_dump($questions);
        if ($questions != false)
        {
            $response["data"] = $questions;
        }
        else
        {
            $response["error"] = "Fehler beim Laden der Fragen (keine Datensätze?)";
        }
    }
    elseif ($tag == 'answeredquestion')
    {
        // Request type is insert a answered question
       $qid = getParamValue('qid');
       $answer = getParamValue('answer');


        // store question
        $question = $db->storeQuestion($qid, $answer);

        if ($question != false)
        {
            // question stored successfully
        }
        else
        {
            // question failed to store
            $response["error"] = "JSON Error occured in saving new question.";
        }
    }
    elseif ($tag == "deletequestion")
    {   
        // delete question
        $question = $db->deleteQuestion();
        //echo var_dump($question);

        if ($question != false)
        {
            // delete question success
        }
        else
        {
            // delete question error
            $response["error"] = "Sie sind noch bei der ersten Frage.";
        }
    }
    elseif ($tag == "solution")
    {   
        // solution
        $solution = $db->setTestDone();
        //echo var_dump($solution);

        if ($solution != false)
        {
            // Evaluation success
            $response["data"] = $solution;
        }
        else
        {
            // Evaluation error
            $response["error"] = "Fehler beim Abschließen des Tests.";
        }
    }
    elseif ($tag == "addpatient" && $isAdmin)
    {
        // Request type is insert a patient
       $pid = getParamValue('pid');
       $svnr = getParamValue('svnr');
       $fname = getParamValue('fname');
       $lname = getParamValue('lname');
       $gender = getParamValue('gender');
       $age = getParamValue('age');
       $created_at = getParamValue('created_at');

        // Add patient
        $patient = $db->addPatient($pid, $svnr, $fname, $lname, $gender, $age, $created_at);

        if ($patient != false)
        {
            // patient stored successfully
        }
        else
        {
            // patient failed to store
            $response["error"] = "JSON Error occured in saving new patient.";
        }
    }
    elseif ($tag == "assigntest" && $isAdmin)
    {
        // Request type is assign test to a patient
       $pid = getParamValue('pid');
       $tid = getParamValue('tid');
       $sessiontoken = getParamValue('sessiontoken');

        // Assign test
        $patienttest = $db->assignTest($pid, $tid, $sessiontoken);

        if ($patienttest != false)
        {
            // patient stored successfully
        }
        else
        {
            // patient failed to store
            $response["error"] = "JSON Error occured in saving new patient.";
        }
    }
    elseif($tag == "getsolutions" && $isAdmin)
    {
        // Request type is getsolutions
        // list solutions
        $solutions = $db->listSolutions();
        //echo var_dump($solutions);
        if ($solutions != false)
        {
            $response["data"] = $solutions;
        }
        else
        {
            $response["error"] = "Fehler beim Laden der Ergebnisse (keine Datensätze?)";
        }
    }
    elseif($tag == "getsolutionscale" && $isAdmin)
    {
        // Request type is getsolutionscale
        $soid = getParamValue('soid');

        // list rawvalue of each scale from a Session
        $solutionscale = $db->listSolutionScale($soid);

        if ($solutionscale != false)
        {
            $response["data"] = $solutionscale;
        }
        else
        {
            $response["error"] = "Fehler beim Laden der Rohwerte (keine Datensätze?)";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Tag ist ungültig
        $response["error"] = "Tag nicht implementiert ($tag)!";
    }
}
else
{
    // Token nicht gültig!
    $response["error"] = $checkToken; 
 } 
echo json_encode($response);
 }
  else
  {
    echo "PHP API for MMPI 2 Soul - lution"; 
  }
 ?>
```

**EDIT:**
That is shown in the label {\"data\"{"\"fname\":\"Hassan\".... 
And the result should be Hassan. How can I do this

**EDIT 2**

```
        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    public String alpha { get; set; }

    private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {              
        String tan = tbtan.Text;
        string html = string.Empty;
        string url = @"http://stidl.workcloud.at/?tag=login&token=" + tan;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        {
            html = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }



        Patient pat = new Patient();
        pat.MyProperty = html;


        pat.Property = tbtan.Text;

        pat.Show();

  }
}
```

}

Comment: Why a dislike ?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, neither “doesn't work” nor “I have a Problem” are questions. What API are you using? WPF? My guess why it “still shows in a Json Format” is because you are specifically setting the content of your `lbquestion` to JSON. You know that JSON is a text format, right? What do you expect it to show if not the text?

Comment: yes i set lbquestion to json but i Serialze it in the line before. I want that the text is shown in a normal string and not in json. And i use WPF

Comment: [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41431095/edit) your question to include that information and your example text, do not post screen shots of text. JSON is a “normal string” so I have no idea what you want; please show an example.

Comment: Click the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41431095/edit) link under your question, put the text in your question and not in an image on an external site. This is important because the search feature does not search the content of external sites and when your link expires your question will no longer make any sense.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the hint. I have edit it.

Comment: you are trying to serialized  property of a class.  Try making it a  class or a structure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is doing exactly what you are telling it to do; convert a string (not HTML) to a JSON object then set `lbuser.Content` to that JSON.

If you are trying to extract elements from JSON you want to do the reverse; extract a string from JSON. [JSON.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) is probably the easiest way to do that, but if you must use `System.Web.Script.Serialization` you can do this:

```
var j = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(html) as Dictionary<string, object>;
var d = j["data"] as Dictionary<string, object>;
lbuser.Content = d["fname"].ToString();
```

Note that the JSON you posted is syntactically incorrect and you didn't even show us the contents, so I am totally guessing as to what keys are available in your real JSON. Inspect its contents in your debugger.

Comment: Thank you, One question what is the meaning of this s --> DeserializeObject(s)

Comment: You need to pass the JSON string you are deserializing; in your case you call it `html` even though it's not HTML. Read my edit.

Comment: I edited my question is that what you need?

Comment: With your code I get System.NullReferenceException. I thin because I set html null but I do not know how I set it.

Comment: Your question is now worse; I mean the “{\"data\"{"\"fname\":\"Hassan\"...” stuff is not JSON. Yes of course if `html` is null you will get a `NullReferenceException` You need to ensure `html` is not null and contains JSON. Please use the debugger; you will need it to inspect the contents of `j` and `d` since you won't tell me what your `html` contains.

Comment: Do you mean breakpoints?

Comment: Yes, setting a breakpoint at `var j = ...` is one way of doing it.

Comment: I get this error :
The holding point is not reached at the moment. No symbols have been loaded for this document

Comment: That's not an error and it means you're not debugging the code you put the breakpoint in.

Comment: Sorry, var j and var d are null

Comment: That means your `html` is not JSON. You need to post the **complete value** of `html` to your question.

Comment: I edited my question. Now the api and my other class are obove

Comment: That is useless, we need to know the value of your `html` variable; it's not HTML and I bet it's not JSON. I can't see your screen, you have to post it to your question and remove all the garbage you've added.

Comment: That is all what i have the html is only a variable that i set null.

Comment: Ok now i have it that is the complete value of html {"data":{"fname":"HASSAN","lname":"ALI","testname":"MMPI2"},"tag":"login","error":null}

Comment: Ok thank you now it is working but it is Json Format or?

Comment: if `JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(s)` returns `null` then `s` is not JSON, if it does not return `null` then `s` is JSON. The code in your comment is JSON but the code in your question is not. Last name in the JSON you posted is `d["lname"]`.

Answer (score 0):

Using structures lend themselves to json serialization well.

```
public String MyProperty { get; set; }

public String Property { get; set; }
[Serializable]
public struct MyStuff
{
        public string MyProperty;

}

private void MyWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MyStuff stuff = new MyStuff();
    stuff.MyProperty = MyProperty;
    String json= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(stuff);

    lbuser.Content = json;
```

Comment: Thank you for helping but it is still a jsonformat

Comment: now I am confused.  You do not need to serialize a string. That is what serialization does, makes a copy of an object and puts it in string format

Comment: lbuser.Content = MyProperty;  is all you need to do

Comment: No I want to filter the Json. I want to show the name

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to achieve?

```
private void MyWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //dynamic convert = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(MyProperty);

    string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(MyProperty);
    lbuser.Content = json;
}
```

you are SERIALIZING the property using a javascript serializer (i.e. creating a JSON), and then you ASIGN the json to the lbuser.Content.

If the data is coming from a JSON then normally you would DESERIALIZE it into either a class that mirrors the JSON properties or a dictionary.

Comment: I want to filter the Json Format. I want to show the name